# Exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' disappears after iteration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
using (context = new DBEntities())
{
    var ordersEnt = context.Orders.Include("Clients");
    return ordersEnt.ToArray();
}
```

The client information contained in `Clients` does not display, I'm receiving this exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

I understand that it's because the code is in the `using()`, so after the code leaves the `using` clause the object is disposed.

If I add

```
foreach (var order in ordersEnt)
{
    string cliName = order.Clients.ClientName;
}
```

without making any further use of `string clientName` the error disappears and the client information contained in `Clients` displays.

Why does iterating solve the problem? Is there a way to achieve this without iterating through the order results?

Comment: Do you add the mentioned code inside the using?

Comment: Your problem most likely has to do with Eager/Lazy loading. I can not provide a solution right out of the top of my head, but this would be the direction to look out.

Comment: @ Marcel Yes it's inside the using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because entity framework uses lazy loading. `ordersEnt.ToArray()` queries the orders only, even you specified `context.Orders.Include("Clients")`, the framework creates a proxy for you like this:

```
//your POCO class here
class Order
{
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//the framework uses something like this
class Order_Proxy : Order
{
    public override Client Client
    {
        get 
        { 
            //return Client_Proxy when you access this property
            //the query executes when accessing
        }
        set { /*blabla*/ }
    }            
}

class Client_Proxy : Client
{
    //a proxy wrapper like Order_Proxy
}
```

So the query happens when `string cliName = order.Clients.ClientName;`. Without it, the query happens outside the `using` block, where the context is disposed, hence the exception.

**The solution** It looks like you are exposing the data entities to the caller, which is not a good idea. If you are building a web-api or something similiar, don't use the entity types as the return type of your api. You can create a new class(maybe named `Order` too) in your api layer, and map the entity to it(using AutoMapper or something similiar). You will have `MyProject.Core.Order` and `MyProject.WebApi.Order`.

Comment: Thank you! How do I map the entity to the new class?